# Error handling and Signals

Tags: elm

I have an Elm app that needs to communicate to a server using `Http` on Elm Platform 0.14.1. The app needs to validate that its requests are valid before sending them to the server.

Currently I am using a function `makeRequest` to take some data from the model and make an `Http.Request` based on it with invalid requests returning `Http.get ""`. This is a hack and I want to replace it with proper error handling.

The types of the functions I have are:

```
makeRequest : List String -> Request String
Http.send : Signal (Request a) -> Signal (Response String)
```

I want to wrap the result of `makeRequest` in `Result` so that I can handle the errors properly. I also want to wrap `Http.send` so that it propagate errors.

Ideally I would like to end up with:

```
newMakeRequest : List String -> Result String (Request String)
newSend : Signal (Result String (Request a)) -> Signal (Result String (Response String))
```

Constructing `newMakeRequest` is trivial. But I am not sure how to approach `newSend` or if it is even possible.

Comment: Wouldn't the types be: `newMakeRequest : List String -> Result error (Request String)`, 
`newSend : Signal (Result error (Request a)) -> Signal (Result error (Response String))`?

Comment: sorry that was a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so all you need is the `newSend` right? That's possible:

```
newSend : Result x (Reponse a) -> Signal (Result x (Request a)) -> Signal (Result x (Response a))
newSend defaultResp s =
  let reqs =
        s |> Signal.keepIf isOk (Ok (Http.get ""))
          |> Signal.map unpackOk
      errs =
        s |> Signal.dropIf isOk defaultResp
          |> Signal.map errIdentity
  in Signal.merge errs (Signal.map Ok (Http.send reqs))

-- Change the type of an Err Result. 
errIdentity : Result x a -> Result x b
errIdentity =
  Result.map (Debug.crash "errIdentity: Don't call this function on an Ok!")

unpackOk : Result x a -> a
unpackOk =
  case res of
    Ok  a -> a
    Err x -> Debug.crash "unpackOk: Don't call this function on an Err!"

isOk : Result x a -> Bool
isOk res =
  case res of
    Ok  _ -> True
    Err _ -> False
```

I'm not sure if you can get rid of the default response. And I am a bit worried about the ordering of events.. The responses are asynchronous, so you may get `Err`s from the input signal on the output signal immediately while an `Ok` request is still pending. Not sure how to fix that. Not sure if that's a problem for you either.